# Deploying wordpress app in Azure virtual directory with asp.net app

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, azure

I have ASP.net app hosted on Azure websites on root. I created a virtual directory for blogs where I want to host wordpress app. I deployed the wordpress app but after (wordpress admin panel) login click it redirects to error page of my asp.net app. The frontend (blog pages) is also not visible.

I assume there might be some URL rewrite issue in Web.config. Also need to change something in wordpress settings. I am not sure.

Update:
I am getting below error when trying to access /blog

Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolKit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Web.config in wwwroot folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- Remove httpcookies in production -->
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="AjaxControlToolKit" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="home.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I create a Azure Web App with `ASP.NET Starter Web App` template, and put a wordpress folder in the root directory, after installing wordpress, it works on my side. Could you provide the `web.config` content in the root directory? And is the wordpress database clean or it has some old wordpress configuration like `Permalink Settings`?

Comment: I have added web.config content in the root directory. Wordpress is clean with fresh database.

Comment: You are getting the error because you have AjaxControlToolkit in a "parent " web.config - in a folder above the Wordpress folder.  Also, this config has removed ALL the default documents and then added "home.htm" as the only default document.  You will at least need index.php as a default document to run Wordpress.

Comment: I understood that I should add index.php in the default document list but what to do to fix the Ajaxcontrol toolkit error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue. I referred to below article to create & host wordpress blog in virtual directory. To fix the "Could not load AjaxControlToolKit.dll" issue, I created a Bin folder within Wordpress folder next to wp-admin and added same dll file there. It's working now. I know it is not the right way to fix it but at this moment I could not find the root cause for same.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/04/19/microsoft-azure-web-sites-deploying-wordpress-to-a-virtual-directory-within-the-azure-web-site/

I did not use above mentioned (in first post) web.config. I just used the default one created through the process mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend putting your asp.net app in a folder under wwwroot and putting the wordpress files in a second folder under wwwroot.  Otherwise, you are going to have conflicts with the web.config. For example, your directory structure:

- wwwroot

  - root (asp.net application)
  - blog2 (Worpress files)

Then in the Azure portal >> Application Settings, setup your virtual directory like this:
[image]

This allows you to independently deploy your asp.net application to root without affecting your Wordpress installation.

Comment: Why Application is not checked for blog2 entry?

Comment: Still same issue. I marked Application as checked as I was not able to publish. I am going to try the suggestion from Gary.

Comment: You should only need to "publish" Wordpress once - preferably by uploading the files, or moving them from the directory they were installed in.